# Select all tags that are user in questions asp.net c# EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

There are four tables:

Questions(questionId, question)
QuestionTags(questionTagId, questionId, tagId)
CodingKeys(codingKeyId, codingTypeId ..)
Codings(codingId, codingKeyId, coding ..)

I want to select all question tagIds and their codings (codingKeyId is foreign key of tagId) that are represented in Questions... So if I have 10 different codings in Codings table but only two of them are represented in Questions I want to select only these two.

I tried with join like this:

```
var query = from qt in context.QuestionTags
    join c in context.Codings on qt.tagId equals c.codingKeyId
    select new
    {
        tagId = qt.tagId,
        coding = c.coding
    };
```

But the above solution gave me double results. For example, if one tag is included in more than one question, I get the same tag twice (I tried distinct, but that didn't work).

I also tried using Any:

```
var query= context.QuestionTags
    .Where(qt => qt.Questions.QuestionTags.Any(q => q.tagId == qt.tagId))
    .Select(qt => new
    {
        codingKeyId = qt.questionId,
        coding = context.Codings.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CodingKeys.codingKeyId == qt.tagId).coding
    });
```

The same thing happened here, I got duplicate results, but `Distinct` didn't work (don't know why).

However, if I use this SQL statement:

```
SELECT distinct tagId, coding 
FROM QuestionTags
LEFT OUTER JOIN Codings ON codingKeyId LIKE QuestionTags.tagId
WHERE Codings.languageId = 1
```

I get the right result, but I don't want to write and store a procedure for this. I really wan't to know if I can solve this with EF (linq), and I am also not sure if distinct is the right solution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group by in order to get just the results you want.
    `var query = from qt in context.QuestionTags`
    `join c in context.Codings on qt.tagId equals c.codingKeyId` 
    `group qt by new {tagId = qt.tagId,coding = c.coding } into element` 
    `select new` 
    `{` 
    `tagId = element.Key.tagId,` 
    `coding = element.Key.coding` 
    `};`

Please mark it as answer if you find it useful

Comment: Which one is better group by or distinct ... I think the result is the same but I wanna know more about performance and optimization

Comment: Please try it with group by the way I have written above. This should help you out. If it does not then let me know what's the issue with this approach. and the good thing about this approach is it will work in all the cases. where as the answer you gave above is dependent on languageid so it's a kind of hard coding things.
thanks.

Comment: In your case you are creating a custom data type so for getting unique results in custom data types group by is the best in my opinion. If you are working with built in datatypes and more over only one value is to be returned then you could have easily used distinct instead of group by so both of them depends upon scenario.

Comment: In your scenario according to me group by suits you :)

Comment: Ok for your efford and everything ... your solution works just like mine ... You give me some new infos and I will trust you with your explanation.. Thanks

Comment: I am here to help and am glad my answer proved useful in some way for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from qt in context.QuestionTags
    join c in context.Codings  on qt.tagId equals c.codingKeyId  
    where c.languageId == 1
    select new
    {
        codingKeyId = qt.tagId,
        coding = c.coding
    };    

    return result.Distinct()
```

Ok, like this it is working, but is this the only way to use it with distinct and join... I am not sure if this is the right solution (but it gives me the right result) ... maybe it can be optimized a bit...

Comment: The same result but sharpthnkr described me why his solution is better in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var query = from qt in context.Codings
join c in context.QuestionTags on qt.tagId equals c.codingKeyId
select new
{
    tagId = qt.tagId,
    coding = c.coding
};
```

Comment: This give me the same result like my first solution posted above ... I get doubled results if the tag is used in two questions I get this tag two times(I try with distinct, but doesnt work...)